# Controlling output frequency of 3 Phase SPWM Inverter

Tags: arduino-mega

I am now on a 3 Phase SPWM inverter project, and i got this code from this [article](http://www.eprojectszone.com/how-to-generate-three-phase-spwm-signal-with-arduino/). It works perfectly on simulation. But the problem is, i can't make the output frequency variable. I intend to vary the frequency at range 0 to 100 Hz and use it to control the speed of 3 phase induction motor. Could anyone help me, please? Any advice or maybe you got a code that works perfectly in controlling spwm inverter frequency. Here is the code of 3 phase spwm inverter. Oh, i am using Arduino Mega by the way.

```
            int i=0;
            int j=0;
            int k=0;
            int x=0;
            int y=0;
            int z=0;
            int OK=0;
            int OK1=0;
            int OK2=0
            int OK3=0;
            int OK4=0;
            int sinPWM[]={1,2,5,7,10,12,15,17,19,22,24,27,30,32,34,37,39,42,
            44,47,49,52,54,57,59,61,64,66,69,71,73,76,78,80,83,85,88,90,92,94,97,99,
            101,103,106,108,110,113,115,117,119,121,124,126,128,130,132,134,136,138,140,142,144,146,
            148,150,152,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,168,169,171,173,175,177,178,180,182,184,185,187,188,190,192,193,
            195,196,198,199,201,202,204,205,207,208,209,211,212,213,215,216,217,219,220,221,222,223,224,225,226,227,
            228,229,230,231,232,233,234,235,236,237,237,238,239,240,240,241,242,242,243,243,244,244,245,245,246,246,
            247,247,247,248,248,248,248,249,249,249,249,249,255,255,255,255,249,249,249,249,249,248,
            248,248,248,247,247,247,246,246,245,245,244,244,243,243,242,242,241,240,240,239,238,237,237,236,235,234,
            233,232,231,230,229,228,227,226,225,224,223,222,221,220,219,217,216,215,213,212,211,209,208,207,205,204,
            202,201,199,198,196,195,193,192,190,188,187,185,184,182,180,178,177,175,173,171,169,168,166,164,162,160,
            158,156,154,152,150,148,146,144,142,140,138,136,134,132,130,128,126,124,121,119,117,115,113,110,108,106,
            103,101,99,97,94,92,90,88,85,83,80,78,76,73,71,69,66,64,61,59,57,54,52,49,47,44,42,39,37,34,32,30,
            27,24,22,19,17,15,12,10,7,5,2,1};

            int potinput = A1;
            int potfreq = A2;
            float potinputval;
            float potfreqval;
            float A;
            float F;

            void setup() {
            Serial.begin(9600);

            pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
            pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
            pinMode(9,OUTPUT);
            pinMode(10,OUTPUT);
            pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
            pinMode(5,OUTPUT);

            cli();// stop interrupts
            TCCR0A=0;//reset the value
            TCCR0B=0;//reset the value
            TCNT0=0;//reset the value
            //0b allow me to write bits in binary
            TCCR0A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
            TCCR0B=0b00000001; //no prescaler



            TCCR2A=0;//reset the value
            TCCR2B=0;//reset the value
            TCNT2=0;//reset the value
            //0b allow me to write bits in binary
            TCCR2A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
            TCCR2B=0b00000001; //no prescaler

            TCCR3A=0;//reset the value
            TCCR3B=0;//reset the value
            TCNT3=0;//reset the value
            //0b allow me to write bits in binary
            TCCR3A=0b10100001;//phase correct pwm mode
            TCCR3B=0b00000001; //no prescaler
            TCCR1A=0;//reset the value
            TCCR1B=0;//reset the value
            TCNT1=0;//reset the value
            OCR1A=509;// compare match value
            TCCR1B=0b00001001; //WGM12 bit is 1 for CTC mode and no prescaler

            TIMSK1 |=(1 << OCIE1A);// enable interrupts

            sei();//stop interrupts
            }
            ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect){// interrupt when timer 1 match with OCR1A value
            if(i>313 && OK==0){// final value from vector for pin 13
            i=0;// go to first value of vector
            OK=1;//enable pin 4
            }
            if(i>313 && OK==1){// final value from vector for pin 4
            i=0;//go to firs value of vector
            OK=0;//enable pin 13
            }
            x = round(A*sinPWM[i]); // x take the value from vector corresponding to position i(i is zero indexed)
            i=i+1;// go to the next position
            if(OK==0){
            OCR0B=0;//make pin 4 0
            OCR0A=x;//enable pin 13 to corresponding duty cycle
            }
            if(OK==1){
            OCR0A=0;//make pin 13 0
            OCR0B=x;//enable pin 4 to corresponding duty cycle
            }

            if ((i==209) || OK1==1){//if i equal with 209 enable second signal
            OK1=1;//mantain if function
            if(j>313 && OK2==0){// final value from vector for pin 10
            j=0;// go to first value of vector
            OK2=1;//enable pin 9
            }
            if(j>313 && OK2==1){// final value from vector for pin 9
            j=0;//go to firs value of vector
            OK2=0;//enable pin 10
            }
            y = round(A*sinPWM[j]);// y take the value from vector corresponding to position j(j is zero indexed)
            j=j+1;// go to the next position
            if(OK2==0){
            OCR2B=0;//make pin 9 0
            OCR2A=y;//enable pin 10 to corresponding duty cycle
            }
            if(OK2==1){
            OCR2A=0;//make pin 10 0
            OCR2B=y;//enable pin 9 to corresponding duty cycle
            }
            }
            if ((j==209) || OK3==1){//if j equal with 209 enable third signal
            OK3=1;//mantain if function
            if(k>313 && OK4==0){// final value from vector for pin 5
            k=0;// go to first value of vector
            OK4=1;//enable pin 2
            }
            if(k>313 && OK4==1){// final value from vector for pin 2
            k=0;//go to firs value of vector
            OK4=0;//enable pin 5
            }
            z=round(A*sinPWM[k]);// z take the value from vector corresponding to position k(k is zero indexed)
            k=k+1;// go to the next position
            if(OK4==0){
            OCR3B=0;//make pin 2 0
            OCR3A=z;//enable pin 5 to corresponding duty cycle
            }
            if(OK4==1){
            OCR3A=0;//make pin 5 0
            OCR3B=z;//enable pin 2 to corresponding duty cycle
        }
        }
        }
        void loop() {

          potinputval = analogRead(potinput);
          A = potinputval/1023;       

          potfreqval = analogRead(potfreq);
          F = map(potfreqval,1023,0,0,50);}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this sketch the PWM values, matching a sampled sine curve, are stored in integer array sinPWM[]. The values from sinPWM (1 - 255) are used unmodified (via intermediate variables x, y and z) to set the various timing registers (OCR0A/B, OCR2A/B and OCR3A/B) which control the pulse width modulation. In this way the amplitude(s) of the generated sine wave(s) will be constant.

If you want to control the speed of the motor you have to multiply the values from sinPWM with a factor between 0 and 1. The most logical place is to do that when the values from sinPWM are transferred to the intermediate variables x, y and z. Example: x=round(0.8 * sinPWM[i]). The factor, 0.8 in this example, you can of course replace by a variable which value is derived from an analogRead() of a pin connected to a potmeter or some sensor. But make sure to convert it to a value in the range 0-1 before you use it in the calculation.

Comment: Ok.. I will try it. But could you tell me why I should multiply the value with  a factor between 0 and 1, please?

Comment: You feed the motor with three sine waves with a mutual phase difference of 120 degrees. The amplitude of the sine wave (= half of the top-top value) determines the speed of the motor. I say this with some reservation because there are many different types of electro motor. I assume you use a three phase motor with a squirrel-cage rotor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So i've tried the formula you've mentioned above without potmeter first ( i multiplied the sinPWM with value between 0-1), and it takes effect on duty cycle values. But when i connect the potmeter and improve the code, it didn't work. I think something's wrong with my analog converting formula.  Would you mind to take a look to my code above, please?

Comment: I will try. But could you first tell me the details about the motor you are using (do you have a datasheet, or manufacturer plus part number)?

Comment: I only have these 2 pictures. Please take a look. 

[Image1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Son3hdQbn8HtUav8BKTaY-q71HG5jRrQ/view)

[Image2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nb-gbeT26wmT9j052lXRBZ-ZfzZIxmJC/view)

Comment: Thanks for the pictures. What circuit do you have between the Arduino and the motor?

Comment: I have 6 gate drivers with 13-14 volt output ( i made my own gate driver with hcpl-3120 IC). Then i have a MOSFET bridge with 6 x Irfp460 MOSFETs. I haven't had a filter yet, because i'm thinking to control the SPWM first. And, it's hard to find references about 3 phase low pass filter.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Indeed you made a mistake with the code for processing the potmeter value. First, you don't have to set the pinMode for this pin (this has no further influance). Second the variable A should be a float (not an int, because an int can't hold fractions). To be sure to avoid integer division and to avoid A having an invalid intermediary value (interruption can happen at any point in the calculation) also make a float of potinputval and do the calculation as follows: potinputval = analogRead(potinput); potinputval = potinputval / 1023; A = potinputval;

Comment: But my (original) answer is not correct. I was under the impression that you were using a small motor (e.g. a toy motor) in an analog way connected to the Arduino.

Comment: I am not a motor expert. But from the plate on the motor it looks like an 3 phase AC asynchronous motor with squirrel cage rotor. If this is correct the motor should have 6 electrical connection points, some of them connected to one of the others (with a metal 'bridge'). The motor can be electrically connected in star or delta configuration (Google on these terms if this is new for you).

Comment: The rotation speed of these motors depends on the frequency of the (electrical) phases. So, if you want to change the speed of the motor, you have to change the frequency of the generated sine waves. Most probably this involves other settings for the various timers. It would take me too much time to figure out how to do this. Maybe somebody else from Stack Overlow can help or maybe the guy running the site were you got your co

Comment: But when i search for 3 phase induction motor controlling method. I found that vary the supply voltage will effect the motor speed. I think that could be work. And do you know how to invert an array or how to invert pwm? The code above provide 6 spwm output. If i put 2 output together, one of them should be inverted. So i need 3 normal output and 3 inverted output. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can't control the speed of this motor by varying the supply voltage. But you can try that out in a simple way: the supply voltage for the motor is applied via your motor driver (H-bridge), so it is relatively easy to vary it. The article you refer to in the 1st line of your question describes how to generate the positive and the 'negative' halves of the three fases. As the Arduino can't generate negative signals also the 'negative' halves of the fases are positive. Inversion has to be done by a separate circuit (which might be integrated in the motor driver circuit).

Comment: Hi PimV, you were right, i have to vary the frequency output of the inverter. The thing is, i haven't find any method to control it. Could you help me once again? Or could you give me some advices or something, please? Thanks in advance.