# Generating variable frequency of 3 phase SPWM

Tags: arduino-mega

I got a sample of program to generate 3 phase SPWM from this [Controlling output frequency of 3 Phase SPWM Inverter](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/59925/controlling-output-frequency-of-3-phase-spwm-inverter). As far as I understood, the frequency generated is constant. My question is how can I make it a variable frequency generated? I am using Arduino mega right now.

Answer (score 1):

I've edited the code in that post to my latest code! I suggest you take a look at the signal on proteus scope, but first try to filter all signals with 1K ohm resistor and 0.37uF capacitor connected in series. Put your scope probe at the end of resistor. Hope that will help!

Comment: can i know what is the max fequency you used in the code? because i'm still trying simulate the code and cant capture the frequency generated. Hope you can clarify me a bit.

Comment: It's around 0 - 200Hz. I've checked using my inverter circuit and Oscilloscope.